# Ordering Arraylist with variable size records

Tags: android, arraylist

Only a couple weeks into android, and im a bit stumped. Any and all insight greatly appreciated.

In this code I found, the author is hard coding the values of setOrderName and Status.

I will be pulling these values from a web service though, it looks in here like I would need the o1,o2,o3 objects to increase based on how many records I pull.  Is this correct? If so, how would I achieve this.

If im babbling, please feel free to ask for specifics.
Thanks in advance

```
 private void getOrders(){
      try{
          m_orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
          Order o1 = new Order();
          o1.setOrderName("SF services");
          o1.setOrderStatus("Pending");
          Order o2 = new Order();
          o2.setOrderName("SF Advertisement");
          o2.setOrderStatus("Completed");
          m_orders.add(o1);
          m_orders.add(o2);
          Thread.sleep(5000);
          Log.i("ARRAY", ""+ m_orders.size());
        } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.e("BACKGROUND_PROC", e.getMessage());
        }
        runOnUiThread(returnRes);
    }

public class Order {


private String orderName;
private String orderStatus;

public String getOrderName() {
    return orderName;
}
public void setOrderName(String orderName) {
    this.orderName = orderName;
}
public String getOrderStatus() {
    return orderStatus;
}
public void setOrderStatus(String orderStatus) {
    this.orderStatus = orderStatus;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple `Order` variables aren't necessary. Instead of:

```
      m_orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
      Order o1 = new Order();
      o1.setOrderName("SF services");
      o1.setOrderStatus("Pending");
      Order o2 = new Order();
      o2.setOrderName("SF Advertisement");
      o2.setOrderStatus("Completed");
      m_orders.add(o1);
      m_orders.add(o2);
```

you can write:

```
      m_orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
      Order o;

      o = new Order();
      o.setOrderName("SF services");
      o.setOrderStatus("Pending");
      m_orders.add(o);

      o = new Order();
      o.setOrderName("SF Advertisement");
      o.setOrderStatus("Completed");
      m_orders.add(o);
```

Note the 4 lines that create and add the order use the same local variable, `o`.

Comment: I was really nervous to post here, since I feel a bit over my head at times.  Thanks for the awesome advice, really means a lot!